# Manually changing date and time of a file

Tags: asp-classic

I'd like to manually change the date and time for a specified time by invoking [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or something similar but on ASP Classic. As far as I know, [ASP File Object](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_file.asp) provides method for retrieving the creation & modification times for the file but provides no methods for actually setting them.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer relatively quickly:

```
Sub ModifyLastAccessedDate(emlFilePath, newDate)
    Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = objFSO.GetFile(emlFilePath)
    Set app = Server.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
    Set folder = app.NameSpace(file.ParentFolder & "\") 
    Set fileModify = folder.ParseName(file.Name) 

    fileModify.ModifyDate = NewDate 

    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing 
    Set folder = Nothing 
    Set app = Nothing 
    Set fileModify = Nothing
End Sub
```

And then you just call the routine by

`Call ModifyLastAccessedDate("C:\Folder\SomeFile.Txt","2013-03-05")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in JScript, and again in VB, taken directly from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787825(v=vs.85).aspx) just for posterity (and as another example of how the date **and time** string can be set):

```
<script language="JScript">
    function fnModifyDateGetSetJ()
    {
        var objShell = new ActiveXObject("shell.application");
        var objFolder2;
        var ssfWINDOWS = 36;

        objFolder2 = objShell.NameSpace(ssfWINDOWS);
        if (objFolder2 != null)
        {
            var objFolderItem;

            objFolderItem = objFolder2.ParseName("NOTEPAD.EXE");
            if (objFolderItem != null)
            {
                var szReturn;

                szReturn = objFolderItem.ModifyDate;
                objFolderItem.ModifyDate = "01/01/1900 6:05:00 PM";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

VB:

```
Private Sub fnModifyDateGetSetVB()
    Dim objShell   As Shell
    Dim objFolder2 As Folder2
    Dim ssfWINDOWS As Long

    ssfWINDOWS = 36
    Set objShell = New Shell
    Set objFolder2 = objShell.NameSpace(ssfWINDOWS)
        If (Not objFolder2 Is Nothing) Then
            Dim objFolderItem As FolderItem

            Set objFolderItem = objFolder2.ParseName("NOTEPAD.EXE")
                If (Not objFolderItem Is Nothing) Then
                    Dim szReturn As String

                    szReturn = objFolderItem.ModifyDate
                    objFolderItem.ModifyDate = "01/01/1900 6:05:00 PM"
                Else
                    'FolderItem object returned nothing.
                End If
            Set objFolderItem = Nothing
        Else
            'Folder object returned nothing.
        End If
    Set objFolder2 = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```